# RoR | Range of Dates not traversing multiple months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to create an array of dates for a calendar where there are a few extra day for the next and previous month that will fill in the week.

Here is my current method to try and get the array

```
def calendar
  selected_month = Date.civil((Time.zone.now.year).to_i, (Time.zone.now.month).to_i)

  start_date = selected_month.beginning_of_month
  start_date.sunday? ? start_date : start_date.beginning_of_week.advance(:days => -1)

  end_date = selected_month.end_of_month
  end_date.sunday? ? end_date.advance(:days => 1).end_of_week : end_date

  #only puts 1-30/31 and does not include the extra off set of days from start and end. :( 
  date_range = (start_date..end_date).to_a   
end
```

The problem is the rang only start at 1 and goes to the end of the month even though the start and end days exceed that.

I'm not married to this way of getting the array so maybe you have a better whole idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to reassign the values of start_date and end_date.

```
  start_date = selected_month.beginning_of_month
  start_date = start_date.sunday? ? start_date : start_date.beginning_of_week.advance(:days => -1)

  end_date = selected_month.end_of_month
  end_date = end_date.sunday? ? end_date.advance(:days => 1).end_of_week : end_date
```